# Cannot use conditional statement in this method. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to send dynamic content to an embed in discord.js. I don't want repeating code as i do already trying to solve this issue. Right now i'm trying to do something like this:

```
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
if (user.afk) .addField(` AFK`, `Reason: ${user.afk_reason}`)
.setTitle('Embed')
```

Now of course this wouldn't work. But what method could I use to do this? I've tried other things like this:

```
(user.afk) ? .addField(` AFK`, `Reason: ${user.afk_reason}`) :
```

But to no avail.

Comment: Can you explain what logic you're trying to represent in your first code block?

Comment: If user.afk is true, it should .addField to the embed. else it should not do nothing and not add a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the instance has a no-op method that returns itself, there's no decent way to do it (and even then, the code would look confusing). Use `if` without chaining instead:

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Embed');
if (user.afk) embed.addField(` AFK`, `Reason: ${user.afk_reason}`);
```

Comment: This works, although it does cancel out the other code below it. For example if I would do     

if (user.afk) embed.addField(` AFK`, `Reason: ${user.afk_reason}`)
    .addField('Test', 'Hello')


Then the .addField under it would not be executed.

Comment: If the order of the calls must be preserved, you'll have to call that separately, without chaining. `embed.addField('Test', 'Hello')`